# How to schedule and send periodic flutter local notifications with callback (which is called before sending the notification) in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-notification

Via flutter app, I need to send periodic local notifications with callback--where callback is called for each period/interval before sending notification.
So far I have tried Timer to schedule periodic local notifications, but it does not work in background i.e. when app is closed. I have also tried flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow, but this one does not have callback, which is called before sending notification. Lastly, I have tried Firebase, but it needs notifications to be set in firebase console. how to get callback notification with completed and pending reports after changes in database.
Please advice a solution for the above given problem.
**This is my code :**

````
import 'package:eclarity/pages/radiologist.dart';
import 'package:eclarity/pages/technici.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:ui';
// import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:eclarity/pages/local_notifications.dart' as notify;

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin fltrNotification;
  String _selectedParam;
  String task;
  String task1;  
  int task2;
  String duration;
  String numCompleted;
  String numCompleted1;
  String numPending;
  String numPending1;
  String role;
  Timer timer;
  
  TextEditingController timeController;
  TextEditingController timeController1 = TextEditingController();

  int val;

  var url =  "http://";
   
 
  var data;
  // Future<Radiologist> _future;

  //Future<Radiologist> fetchReportStatus() async {
  fetchReportStatus() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int userPk = prefs?.getInt("userPk");

    String startDate2 = prefs?.getString("notifyDateTime");
    String startDate = prefs?.getString("loginDateTime");

    var currentTime =
        DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a').format(DateTime.now());

    String role = prefs?.getString("role");
    bool userIsTechnician = true;
    if (role == "ROLE_RADIOLOGIST") {
      userIsTechnician = false;
    }

    //userIsTechnician
    Map data1 = {
      'authUserPk': userPk,
      "startDate": startDate,
      "endDate": currentTime,
      "userIsTechnician": userIsTechnician
    };

    String body1 = json.encode(data1);

    final response = await http.post(url,
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: body1);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      if (userIsTechnician) {
        Technici r = Technici.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
        this.numCompleted = r.numCompleted;
        this.numPending = r.numPending;
        print("tech===============" + response.body);
      } else {
        Radiologist r = Radiologist.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
        this.numCompleted = r.numCompleted;
        this.numPending = r.numPending;
        print("rad===============" + response.body);

      }

      //return Radiologist.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load report count');
    }
  }

/// The name associated with the UI isolate's [SendPort].
 String isolateName = 'isolate';

// /// A port used to communicate from a background isolate to the UI isolate.
final ReceivePort port = ReceivePort();
static SendPort uiSendPort;

  Future<void> showNotification(data) async {
    print(data);
    var rand = Random();
    var hash = rand.nextInt(100);
    DateTime now = DateTime.now().toUtc().add(Duration(seconds: 1));

    await notify.singleNotification(
      now,
      "Hello $hash",
      "This is hello message",
      hash,
    );
  }

  // The callback for our alarm
   Future<void> callback() async {
    print('Alarm fired!');
    // // This will be null if we're running in the background.
    uiSendPort ??= IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(isolateName);
    uiSendPort?.send("hi");

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _future =
    // fetchReportStatus();
   // repeatNotification();
//_showNotification();
  port.listen((data) async => await showNotification(data));

    runAlarm();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      timeController1.text = await getPrefForTimer3();
    });
   
    getPrefForTimer2().then((s) {
        task1 = s.toString();
    });
    
     getPrefForDuration().then((s) {
        _selectedParam = s;
    });

    var androidInitilize = new AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    var iOSinitilize = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initilizationsSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        android: androidInitilize, iOS: iOSinitilize);
    fltrNotification = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    fltrNotification.initialize(initilizationsSettings,
        onSelectNotification: notificationSelected);

      setDurationAndShowNotification();
     //  timerNotification(false);

  }

   void runAlarm() async {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 1),
      0,
      callback,
      rescheduleOnReboot: true,
      exact: true,
      wakeup: true,
    );
    print("OK");
  }

   Future<String> getPrefForTimer3() async {
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
         int taskInt = prefs.getInt("task") ?? 30;
         this.task1 = taskInt.toString();
        return this.task1;
   }
   Future<int> getPrefForTimer1() async {
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
         int taskInt = prefs.getInt("task") ?? 30;
         this.task1 = taskInt.toString();
        return taskInt;
   }
  Future<int> getPrefForTimer2() async {
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

         int taskInt = prefs.getInt("task") ?? 30;
         task1 = taskInt.toString();
                 return taskInt;

   }
  setPrefForTimer1(int val) async {
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      // setState(() {   
        prefs.setInt("task", val);
     //  });
   }

Future<String> getPrefForDuration() async {
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      setState(() {
        duration = prefs.getString("duration").toString() ?? "Minutes";
       });
        return duration;
   }
  setPrefForDuration(String val) async {
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        //setState(() {

        prefs.setString("duration", val);
       // });
   }
   

   getPrefForNumPending() async {
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        this.numPending1 = prefs.getInt("numPending").toString() ?? "-1";
   }
  setPrefForNumPending(String val) async {
       if (val == null) {return;}
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setInt("numPending", int.parse(val));
   }

    getPrefForNumCompleted() async {
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        this.numCompleted1 = prefs.getInt("numCompleted").toString() ?? "0";
   }

    setPrefForNumCompleted(String val) async {
       if (val == null) {return;}
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setInt("numCompleted", int.parse(val));
   }
   Future<bool> getUserIsTechnician() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String role = prefs?.getString("role");
    bool userIsTechnician = true;
    if (role == "ROLE_RADIOLOGIST") {
      userIsTechnician = false;
    }
    return userIsTechnician;
   }

  timerNotificationRestart() {
    if (this.task1 != null) {
      setPrefForTimer1(int.parse(this.task1));
    }
    //timerNotification(true);
  }

   timerNotification1(bool stop)  {
    if (stop && this.timer != null) {
      this.timer.cancel();
    }

    //getPrefForTimer1();
   if (this.task1 == null) {
     this.task2 = 30;
    } else {
      this.task2 = int.parse(task1);
    }
    
    Duration duration;
    if (_selectedParam == "Hour") {
      duration = Duration(hours: this.task2);
    } else {
      duration = Duration(minutes: this.task2);
    }
    
     
    bool isStopped = false;
    this.timer = Timer.periodic(duration, (timer1) async {
      // Make a local notification
      if (isStopped) {
        timer1.cancel();
      }


      var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          ticker: 'ticker');
      var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
      var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
          android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
          iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

     await fetchReportStatus();


    var value = await getUserIsTechnician();

     if (!value)  {

      getPrefForNumPending();

     bool sendNotification = false;
      if (this.numPending1 != null && this.numPending != null 
      && this.numPending != this.numPending1) {
        sendNotification = true;
      } else if (this.numPending1 == null) {
        sendNotification = true;
      }

      setPrefForNumPending(this.numPending);
      if (sendNotification) {
      await fltrNotification.show(
        
          0, "",
        // "# Report Completed :" +
        //     this.numCompleted +
        //     "\n",
        "# Report Pending : " +
            this.numPending, platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: 'item x');
      }
      }  else {
  getPrefForNumCompleted();
      bool sendNotification = false;
      if (this.numCompleted1 != null && this.numCompleted != null 
      && this.numCompleted != this.numCompleted1) {
        sendNotification = true;
      } else if (this.numCompleted1 == null) {
        sendNotification = true;
      }
      setPrefForNumCompleted(this.numCompleted);
      if (sendNotification) {
      await fltrNotification.show(
        
          0, "",
        // "# Report Completed :" +
        //     this.numCompleted +
        //     "\n",
        "# Report Completed : " +
            this.numCompleted, platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: 'item x');

      }
      
      }

    });
  }
setDurationAndShowNotification() async {
   await fltrNotification.cancelAll();
  //await fltrNotification.cancel(1);
  
   showNotification1();
}


showNotification1() async {
// var scheduledNotificationDateTime =
   //     new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(seconds: 5));
  // Show a notification every minute with the first appearance happening a minute after invoking the method
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new AndroidNotificationDetails('repeating channel id 1',
        'repeating channel name 1', 'repeating description 1');
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new IOSNotificationDetails();
var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
    android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    await fetchReportStatus();

    var value = await getUserIsTechnician();

   var interval;
    if (_selectedParam == "Hour") {
      interval = RepeatInterval.hourly;
    } else {
      interval = RepeatInterval.everyMinute;

    }
    
     if (!value)  {

     await getPrefForNumPending();
     bool sendNotification = false;
      if (this.numPending1 != null && this.numPending != null 
      && this.numPending != this.numPending1) {
        sendNotification = true;
      } else if (this.numPending1 == null) {
        sendNotification = true;
      }
        print("=========== About to send Rad Notification");
        print("num pending ===== " + this.numPending);
        print("num pending1 ===== " + this.numPending1);
        print("sendNotification ===== " + sendNotification.toString());

      setPrefForNumPending(this.numPending);
      if (sendNotification) {

        await fltrNotification.periodicallyShow(

        
          0, "eClarity Reprot Status",
        // "# Report Completed :" +
        //     this.numCompleted +
        //     "\n",
        "# Report Pending : " + this.numPending, 
        interval, platformChannelSpecifics,
          );
      }
      }  else {
  getPrefForNumCompleted();
      bool sendNotification = false;
      if (this.numCompleted1 != null && this.numCompleted != null 
      && this.numCompleted != this.numCompleted1) {
        sendNotification = true;
      } else if (this.numCompleted1 == null) {
        sendNotification = true;
      }

       print("=========== About to send Rad Notification");
        print("num completed ===== " + this.numCompleted.toString());
        print("num completed1 ===== " + this.numCompleted1.toString());
        print("sendNotification ===== " + sendNotification.toString());


      setPrefForNumCompleted(this.numCompleted);
      if (sendNotification) {
      await fltrNotification.periodicallyShow(
        
          0, "eClarity Reprot Status",
        // "# Report Completed :" +
        //     this.numCompleted +
        //     "\n", 
        "# Report Completed : " +
            this.numCompleted, interval, platformChannelSpecifics,
          );

      }
      
      }
}```
````